# How can i call function from c++ console project in CLR c++ window form?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, clr

I have two projects the first is c++ console application and the second is c++ CLR Empty project .I want to call function from the console and use it in CLR project .I tried to create header file , include it in CLR project and use #include "headername.h" and call the function render3d() but it gives me those linking errors .

> Error 29  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000934) "void __cdecl
>   render3d(void)" (?render3d@@$$FYAXXZ) referenced in function "private:
>   void __clrcall DEMO::MainForm::AddAnimebutton_Click(class
>   System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)"
>   (?AddAnimebutton_Click@MainForm@DEMO@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)   E:\Graduation
>   Project\CPP ARENA DEMO New Design\DEMO\DEMO\MainForm.obj  DEMO
>
> Error 30  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   render3d(void)" (?render3d@@$$FYAXXZ) referenced in function "private:
>   void __clrcall DEMO::MainForm::AddAnimebutton_Click(class
>   System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)"
>   (?AddAnimebutton_Click@MainForm@DEMO@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)   E:\Graduation
>   Project\CPP ARENA DEMO New Design\DEMO\DEMO\MainForm.obj  DEMO
>
> Error 31  error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   E:\Graduation
>   Project\CPP ARENA DEMO New Design\DEMO\Release\DEMO.exe   DEMO

Comment: I'd make a header-only module, but you might find it easier to just create a traditional header+impl module. You can then just use those source files directly, or create a library.

Comment: in console project i have too many source files so it gives me too many errors every time i try too use those source files in the CLR project . that why i can not use it directly .

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to create a library containing the function you want to call and add a dependency between the projects. Your visual studio solution would then contain 3 projects:

- library with render3d function
- console application which references the above library
- CLR empty project which references the above library

Comment: do mean i use library with render3d function as connection between other two projects ?

Comment: I meant that you probably need to put the function in another library if you want to be able to use it both in the console application and your CLR project. After you do that, you should be able to add a reference from the console project and from CLR project to the library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: i added reference from console to library ,from library to CLR and write this code in library .It gives me this linking error again.

error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000005) "void __cdecl render3d(void)" (?render3d@@$$FYAXXZ) referenced in function "public: static void __clrcall ClassLibrary::Class1::callrender(void)" (?callrender@Class1@ClassLibrary@@$$FSMXXZ)

Comment: the code i write '// ClassLibrary.h
#pragma once
using namespace System;
namespace ClassLibrary {

 public ref class Class1
 {
  public:
   static void callrender();
 };
}'

'// This is the main DLL file.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ClassLibrary.h"
#include "Main.h"
namespace ClassLibrary {

 void Class1::callrender(){
  render3d();
 }
  
}'